# How to get attachment(s) content > ~35MB by OWA REST API?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app

I'm developing OWA add-in using OWA REST API

I got bad request `400` status code when trying to get the attachment bigger than 35MB by OWA REST API

In Outlook, the user were able to upload attachment up to ~35MB, getting the content byte by OWA REST API was working perfectly.

That's changed, so now the maximum size limit is ~140MB, but getting the attachment content for one attachment that is bigger than 35MB by either:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/messageId/attachments/attachmentId
```

or

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/messageId/attachments
```

returning 400 with error:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorMessageSizeExceeded","message":"The message exceeds the maximum supported size., The message exceeds the maximum supported size."}}
```

Note that if the user upload for example 10 attachments 14MB each, get attachment by REST API will work fine, but only if the attachment is bigger that 35MB will got that error.

Is it a bug or by design?

If this by design, is there any other way to fetch >35MB attachment?