# How to fetch a specific inline image using OWA REST API?

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm developing OWA add-in using OWA REST API

When fetching the message item, I can see in the body if there's an inline image added which is looks like

```
<p style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0">
    <img class="EmojiInsert" src="cid:773570bf-3178-41a4-97ac-4e3eddef859f" style="">
    <br>
</p>
```

in the `src` I can see the contentId of the attachment but [the resource reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#FileAttachmentResource) did not says if this property is searchable or filterable, and I cant `$select` it in the odata query params, therefore I cant get that attachment!

the alternative way was to fetch the list of the attachments by doing:

`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments`

but that will:

1- fetch all attachments with their `contentBytes` which is too expensive!

2- if the admin increase the minimum upload to be more than 35MB I might got error with that request i single attachment >35MB, [see this question that no one answer it yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934389/how-to-get-attachments-content-35mb-by-owa-rest-api)

3- I alway got some attachments that I did not upload, sometime from outlook it self (VERY WIERD) other time if I upload an attachment(s) and remove it I still get it when fetching the attachments, so some time I have for example 3 attachments but I got 12!!

Is there a way to know the inline image attachment id? and then get that attachment?

Comment: #1. Have you tried addin api to get properties about attachment? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item#attachments-arrayattachmentdetails  You can use that to get Id, and decide which attachment you actually want to download with REST. On #3, there are a few possibilities: signatures with images, item not yet synced with server (in compose case), or some object you can insert to message may consist of multiple attachments.

Comment: I looked up into the this link, the only method is `getAttachmentsAsync` which is in preview and it does not give the contentId as it's `AttachmentDetails` interface which is BTW the same result that I can get from the rest api if I exclude `contentBytes` and still not able to get attachment from it's contentId!
Also: getAttachmentsAsync is giving a weird response, it gives `isInline: true` for normal attachments

Comment: Another thing: I got `(redirected from ' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
when I do getAttachmentContentAsync from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getattachmentcontentasyncattachmentid-options-callback--attachmentcontent